# Rails4 ActiveRecord Association: create a parent and child record at the same time using a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've been trying to get this to work for a while, would appreciate it if someone could let me know if i am on the right path or point me to some documentation which may help.:

I have two active record models, Parent.rb and Child.rb (which has `belongs_to: parent` set).
I'm trying to create a parent then a child record at the same time and associate them(so that if a child record is invalid, the parent is not created at all).

below is what i have so far:

`create_child.haml`

```
= be_form_for @child do |f|
  = ff.text_field :name, 'child name'
  = f.fields_for :parent do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :name, 'parent name'

  = f.submit_tag 'Create'
```

`children_controller.rb`
children_controller.rb

```
def create
  Parent.create(child_params[:parent])
  Child.create(child_params)
end

def child_params
  params.require(:child).permit(:name, :parent)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot missing in this code. 
railscasts.com is an old resource but this link covers the idea which is still used.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

As a general idea:

- create a form for parent model, then put fields for child(ren) inside
- use accepts_nested_attributes_for, it will automatically create two objects and show errors when one is not valid
- I think you can enforce a child on form, but it is not natural order I believe
- create method needs some validation, please follow what rails guides say about standard behavious

It can look like below

`def create
  @parent = Parent.new(parent_params) # params include child params as well, accepting nested attributes resolves that
  if @parent.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end`

Answer (score 1):

I know what you're more or less trying to do, and this would be my suggestions as the "railsiest" way possible:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :child

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :age, presence: true
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :age, presence: true
    validates :favorite_color, presence: true
end


class ParentsController < ApplicationController
    # Display the form and initialize the form variables
    def new
        @parent = Parent.new
        @parent.build_child  #=> use if has_one relationship
        @parent.childs.build #=> use if has_many relationship
    end

    def create
        @parent = Parent.new(parent_params)

        if @parent.save
            flash[:notice] = "Parent and child were successfully saved."
            redirect_to some_path
        else
            flash[:error] = "Could not create parent and child."
            render :new
        end
    end

    private
    def parent_params
        params.require(:parent).permit(:name, :age, child_attributes: [:name, :age, :favorite_color])
    end
end
```

In your view (since you're using haml):

```
= form_for @parent do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.text_field :age

  / Here's the magic
  = f.fields_for :child do |c|
    = c.text_field :name
    = c.text_field :age
    = c.text_field :favorite_color

    = f.submit :submit
```

If you add the proper validations to both models, when using the `fields_for` method in your view, Rails will not save the Parent or the Child when so long as the Child and Parent validations pass for each.